# Dart: Transforming a command line application

Tags: dart

Is it possible to run transformer on a command line application before running it?

For example, if I have a class that mixes in Observable class. And I would like to transform it so that dirtCheck is transformed into ChangeNotifier.

**holder.dart**

```
class Member extends Object with ChangeNotifier {
  @observable
  String name = "";
}

class Holder extends Object with ChangeNotifier {
  Holder() {
  }

  @observable
  Member member = new Member();
}
```

**pubspec.yml**

```
transformers:
- observe:
  files:
    - bin/models/holder.dart
```

If I run this application from IntelliJ IDE, it doesn't seem to run the transformer on it before executing main.dart.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transfomers are not applied to command line apps. Only code that is served using `pub serve` or `pub build` runs and applies transformers. Your code should run on the server/command line as is. There is no need to run transformers.

Transformers are used for observe to replace `dart:mirrors` access by generated code to prevent code bloat for dart2js-generated JS but this is no issue on the command line.

Comment: Observe transformers are not only to replace dart:mirrors for dart2js, they also avoid dirtyCheck by replacing dirtyCheck with using ChangeNotifier.

Comment: That's possible, I didn't investigate that closely but either observe is built only with the client in mind or it was considered acceptable to work this way on the console. https://github.com/dart-lang/build is a new approach that can also be used for console applications but AFAIK observe isn't yet adapted for build.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like a better approach. Love incremental builds and run without transformers feature. Will follow the `build` package closely.